# Reopen DOC file in write mode, with macro inside it

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using a macro template for particular *DOC* files only. It runs only for these files and, as I assume, it is treated as the *DOC* file itself.

All I want is to remove the file *OR* clear the contents of it, after the macro finishes. The initial file is **read-only**.

I have tried:

1. *SavingAs* in *TEMP* folder, change file attribute of initial file and then try to *Kill* it - no luck, it seems that initial file is still preloaded(?) and does not know that the read-only flag was removed. Error: Permision denied.
2. When I try to *Close* the initial document, I am closing also the macro itself...

So:

Is there any way to (from the macro inside the DOC file) :

1. Reopen the file in **write-mode**? (so I could clear the contents afterwards)
2. Remove the initial file? (after **SaveAs** so I actually will have a new file in **write-mode** and will be able to remove initial file)

Comment: It's not clear what you have, how it's working or what you're asking. Are you using a doc file or a template file (dot / dotm)? Which file are you trying to "clear" (and why)? Does the information in this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49731957/3077495 help?

Comment: I have a macro in the template (DOT file) and the read-only DOC file. The macro in template, fills up the DOC file when the DOC file is opened with some personal data, which, when the DOC file is being closed, I would like to clear (or just remove the DOC file).

Comment: So, I'm having trouble understanding: Why not simply never save the doc file? In any case, the same macro container (template) cannot delete this file - logically enough. You could have another template that the macro loads as an Add-in. Possibly it would work to have a macro that triggers when the document closes that calls a macro in the add-in template. It would probably need to use Application.OnTime with a long-ish delay that then attempts to delete the file.

Comment: Because the DOC file is downloaded and contains multiple "markers" that are then replaced with personal details by the template's macro. The DOC file (filled with personal details) is then "SavedAs" temp file, sent to remote server and afterwards it is cleared (temp file). The only problem here is to clear or somehow remove the original DOC file, as when opened again it fills personal details again and it is not desirable...

Comment: Thank you for the additional detail. What I've often seen in similar cases is that the macro "kills" the "temp doc" when *next* it runs. By then, the file should have been released.

Comment: But there is no problem with removing the contents of temp-file. I need to remove the contents of the initial file so it would not be possible to run the macro again.

Comment: ActiveDocument.Content.Delete should work...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170230/discussion-between-mr-p-and-cindy-meister).