# Prevent Word template from being saved over; Word doc is generated from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am using VBA in Excel to generate a shipping label in Word from a Word template. One time, after the Word doc was successfully opened and populated with my data, I accidentally saved over my original template when I closed it.

I want to prevent the user from being able to do this. If they close the Word doc without saving it first, I want them to be prompted to SaveAs, not to save over the existing template, and I want that SaveAs prompt to default to a .doc or .docx file, not a .dotx template file. If they hit the save button or Ctrl+S instead of just closing the document, I want the same SaveAs prompt to appear instead of overwriting my template.

For reference, I'll include the code that opens up my Word template. I declare my objects using Object instead of Word.Application to prevent missing reference errors for users who don't have references to the Word object library set up on their computers. This will be used on a few different computers, and they don't all have the same version of Office, so if you can think of anything else I can do to maintain compatibility I would love to hear it.

Since this involves the saving of a Word document generated from an Excel workbook, I'm not sure how to write event handling for this. Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

```
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim objRange As Object
Dim objDoc As Object

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("[template file location]")

With wdApp

    .Visible = True  
    .Activate  

   'Code that places strings at bookmark locations
    Set objRange = objDoc.Bookmarks("bookmarkName").Range  
    objRange.InsertAfter (stringName)  

End With
```

Comment: Copy it first to a default location and then open it. That way, the original file will not be overwritten.

Comment: Will that save a new copy of the template every time it is opened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying contents of Word doc to newly created Word doc from excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49703241/copying-contents-of-word-doc-to-newly-created-word-doc-from-excel-vba)

Comment: @ARodrigo Yes, it will save a new one. But that will preserve your original file. Also, you can edit the template and update it anytime as it will not be locked when someone uses it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Set objDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open("[template file location]"). The correct syntax is to use

```
Set objDoc = wdApp.Documents.Add("[template file location]")
```

This will add a document based on the specified template. There are more arguments you can pass, including the *DocumentType* which would specify whether the new document is of docx format.

Comment: Thank you for finding the other thread! And thank @Variatus for letting me know that I can specify the extension of the added document. That solved my issue. If I don't specify the extension though, will it automatically choose the default for the user? Like if they're using Office 2003 will it default to .doc?

Comment: This is what MSDN says: Can be one of the following WdNewDocumentType constants: wdNewBlankDocument , wdNewEmailMessage , wdNewFrameset , or wdNewWebPage. The default constant is wdNewBlankDocument. Actually, the question of docx or dotm would arise only at the time of saving. The newly added document is unspecified in this regard.